# Python exponentiation of two lists performance

Tags: python, performance, list, exponentiation

Is there a way to compute the [Cobb-Douglas utility function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobb%E2%80%93Douglas_production_function#Cobb.E2.80.93Douglas_utilities) faster in Python. I run it millions of time, so a speed increase would help. The function raises elements of quantities_list to power of corresponding elements of exponents list, and then multiplies all the resulting elements.

```
n = 10

quantities = range(n)
exponents = range(n)

def Cobb_Douglas(quantities_list, exponents_list):
    number_of_variables = len(quantities_list)
    value = 1
    for variable in xrange(number_of_variables):
        value *= quantities_list[variable] ** exponents_list[variable]
    return value

t0 = time.time()
for i in xrange(100000):
    Cobb_Douglas(quantities, exponents)
t1 = time.time()
print t1-t0
```

Comment: Take a look at the `numpy` library for fast numeric operations.

Comment: Numpy is a slower in this case

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027863/cobb-douglas-functions-slows-running-tremendously-how-to-expedite-a-non-linear) question? It offers a potential speed up.

Comment: It's slower for that example, but for n=20 it appears to be faster.  The main problem is it will lose precision.  Do you need every digit of the result?  Also, your code already seems pretty fast (0.345 seconds for your 100000 loops on my machine).  How fast do you need it to be?  What kinds of values will you be running it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators are your friend. I got a 28% speedup on my computer by switching your loop to this:

```
for q, e in itertools.izip(quantities_list, exponents_list):
    value *= q ** e
```

I also got similar results when switching your loop to a `functools.reduce` call, so it's not worth providing a code sample.

---

In general, `numpy` is the right choice for fast arithmetic operations, but `numpy`'s largest integer type is 64 bits, which won't hold the result for your example. If you're using a different numeric range or arithmetic type, `numpy` is king:

```
quantities = np.array(quantities, dtype=np.int64)
exponents = np.array(exponents, dtype=np.int64)

def Cobb_Douglas(quantities_list, exponents_list):
    return np.product(np.power(quantities_list, exponents_list))
# result: 2649120435010011136
# actual: 21577941222941856209168026828800000
```

Comment: Thanks. I too get a 10-25% speedup with itertools, but almost 5 times slowdown with numpy.. I am using a Mac

Comment: Weird—same. What's the actual dataset you're computing on? Its size and data type can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of suggestions:

1. Use Numpy
2. Vectorize your code
3. If quantities are large and and nothing's going to be zero or negative, work in log-space.

I got about a 15% speedup locally using:

```
def np_Cobb_Douglas(quantities_list, exponents_list):
    return np.product(np.power(quantities_list, exponents_list))
```

And about 40% using:

```
def np_log_Cobb_Douglas(quantities_list, exponents_list):
    return np.exp(np.dot(np.log(quantities_list), np.log(exponents_list)))
```

Last but not least, there should be some scaling of your Cobb-Douglas parameters so you don't run into overflow errors (if I'm remembering my intro macro correctly).

Comment: Maybe you can expand on what your application/implementation is? Doing this using vectors/BLAS should provide a decent speedup, which is what I see using the minimal code you provided.